# how to Generate PWM using Atmega32 for sine wave inverter

Tags: microcontroller, atmega

I am currently working in a Sine wave inverter project, and i need to generate PWM using microcontroller, for that purpose i have chosed atmega32, can somebody guide me from where to start and how to proeceed in writing code for pwm generation using atmega32, any response would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: can you please also tell which type of pwm i have to use for this project, fast pwm, phase correct or  phase and frequency correct pwm

Answer (score 1):

You need to work out a series of PWM values that you will change on a periodic basis that, when filtered with some hardware, will give you a sine wave.

You can do this by creating a spreadsheet, with a column 0-359 (in steps of one) which you then turn into a sine value for each angle. If you then multiple this by a value of 0-2^16 (and use timer 1 which is a 16 bit timer), you will get 360 different PWM values.

You can then play around with these values by, for example, changing the PWM value on each timer period. You could let each PWM value be repeated a few times and watch the frequency of the sine wave change. You could only use every other PWM value before changing the PWM value and watch the frequency double. If you change the multiplier, you will see the sine wave output change in size.

When I talk about the PWM value I am talking about the value that changes the mark to space ratio of the PWM's output. With a more advanced processor, like an STM32, you can get the DMA to automatically do this every time a PWM period elapses. With the Mega32 you will have to do this manually. (ie On the timer interrupt when a period is complete.)

You need to assign the output of the PWM to a pin, then you can connect an RC filter to that pin. If you look with a scope at that output, you'll see the sine wave. 10k/100n is perfectly fine as a starting filter. (10k in series with the output pin, 100n to ground, measure on the RC junction).

As far as what type of PWM, have a play and convince yourself of what is best. Do a simple count up to x, then go high, then stay high until the counter hits 0xFFFF type, then try centre aligned and any other type. FWIW, centre aligned gives best EMC results if you're driving a three phase motor.

I suspect you should research and read the data sheet to learn how to output PWMs. You *need* to understand this if you're going to become a half-decent engineer. Being spoon-fed the code to do it will not help.

Comment: user2447233 thanks for taking time and replying to my query, usually if we are doing it with ICs, to generate a PWM first we take a sine wave (or generate one) of let say 50 Hz then we take a triangular wave of let say 3 KHz and then we compare both of them and get the PWM signal, finally we send this PWM signal to the H-Bridge.


that much theory part i know and i have already implemented the same using ICs but instead of using ICs (or OpAmp) i want to use microcontroller to generate PWM and then feed the PWM signal to H-Bridge,



So can't i generate PWM signal directly from atmega32 ??

Comment: or do i have to first generate 50 Hz sine wave signal using atmega32 as you have explained by using sine table, and similarly generate a triangular wave, and feed these wave to a Comparator to generate PWM and then feed this PWM to h bridge

Comment: The one way you could use to generate a good pure sine wave from a micro is if the micro has an on-chip DAC. You'd send tables of sine values to the DAC in exactly the same way as you do for the PWM. The Mega32 doesn't have a DAC, but there are some megas that have one, some xmegas that have up to four (and have DMA control) and loads of ARMs that will do it. I don't understand the theory behind the sine/triangle wave set-up you use so can't comment on that, but if you had a dual DAC you could so that and manipulate amplitude with op amps easily enough.

Comment: I'm interested to know why you use the dual wave method! (Not being sarcastic, just interested what benefits it has).

Comment: That is how usually SPWM is generated by comparing Sine Wave and a Triangular Wave, 
The reason why i am generating a sine wave is because i also need to generate a third harmonic sine wave and add both sin (50hz) and sin(150hz) signal which would give me 15% more output

Answer (score 0):

I think the way i can generate PWM is by setting the reference value OCR1A = rand(0,255); (using random function) so everytime the loops run it will change my reference value and compare it with triangular wave or ramp wave by increasing the value of TCNT0 from 0 to 255 and then back to 0, else decrease it again from 255 to 0 in order to generate triangular wave. so in this way i can get waveform of different duty cycle, which is what i want as PWM.

Any suggestion will be appreciated